# css3, the variations of "transform: scale()" does not work on any browser apart from Firefox

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I am currently using Vue CLI 3. In the css, I have set up a hover script which increases the scale by 10% when hovering over the div. I have:

```
(this.boxData.scaleOnHover ? 
`-webkit-transform: scale(${this.scale}%);
-moz-transform:    scale(${this.scale}%);
-ms-transform:     scale(${this.scale}%);
-o-transform:      scale(${this.scale}%);
transform:         scale(${this.scale}%);` 
: "");
```

Other css:

```css
        * {
            background: none;
            background-color: none;
        }

        .textbox {
            border-color: #d3d3d3;
            border-radius: 40px;
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: top;
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
        }

        img {
            border-radius: 100px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        p {
            font-size: 1em;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            color: #000000;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 2.5em;
            margin-bottom: 0.25em;
            color: #1b941e;
            text-align: center;
        }

        h2 {
            font-size: 1.5em;
            margin-top: 0.25em;
            margin-bottom: 0.25em;
            color: #22b926;
            text-align: center;
            font-style: italic;
        }
```

However, the scale enlargement only works for Firefox, despite having -webkit-, -ms-, and -o- transforms. What is wrong with the styling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`scale()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale) takes a [<number>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/number), not sure why Firefox accepts percentages here, but for your case, simply do

```
(this.boxData.scaleOnHover ? 
  `transform: scale(${this.scale / 100});`
```